# How to connect Mongodb with mongoose in current Next.js 13.3 Version?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, error-handling, next.js13

I am trying to connect mongodb with the help of mongoose in Next.js 13.3 Version but it is giving different errors when i import the connectDb file or UserSchema file in api/getProducts/route.js file.
Please Help and tell step wise how to connect I am stuck!

First I have created mongoose.js file in a folder named middleware:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const connectDb = (handler) => async (req, res) => {
  if (mongoose.connections[0].readyState) {
    return handler(req, res);
  }
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
  return handler(req, res);
};

export default connectDb;
```

Then I have made Schema of user like this in models/User.js :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

mongoose.models = {};
export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

But when in api/getProducts/route.js file when importing whether connectDb or User schema gives error:

```
import connectDb from "../../../middleware/mongoose";

export async function GET(request) {
  return new Response("Hello, Next.js!");
}
```

Comment: Please provide us the error log your have

Comment: So, the problem is solved. basically it occurs in latest version of mongoose v ^7.1.0. If anyone is facing same problem then just try to downgrade the version and the problem is solved or if you want to continue with latest version then paste this in next.config :   serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"], and the problem will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

```js
import connectDb from "../../../middleware/mongoose";

export const GET = connectDb(async(request) => {
  return new Response("Hello, Next.js!");
})
```